# Sonarqube Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find

Tags: sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

Unable to perform analysis with `sonarqube-5.6.5` and `sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24.`

System Config: 64 bit, Win 7
Java: JAVA 8 U 60/64 bit

Getting error in last step while performing analysis:
`call C:\TestTools\SonarSetup\sonar-scanner-msbuild- 2.2.0.24\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end`

[MSBUILS SONAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSMnC.png)

Facing one more error prior to this step: while Trying to start sonar services from below path

`C:\####\SonarSetup\sonarqube-5.6.5\bin\windows-x86-64\`

please refer to snap shot
[sonar service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCCY6.png)

Comment: please refer embedded snapshots.